# Infinite self invoking function

Tags: javascript, function, loops, setinterval

I am working on a piece of code that is supposed to randomly display a view count on my site. It all works fine, except that it only runs once on page load. Its supposed to change the view count every 10 seconds after the initial first run. E.g. run this code snippet every 10 seconds after page load. I have tried multiple ways with `setInterval` but found that it is supposedly bad practice to use anyways after so many failed attempts?

Could you guys point me in the right direction. I have been reading posts on Stack overflow for hours and none had an answer to my issue. I have a feeling, that I am overlooking something obvious here.

```js
document.addEventListener('page:loaded', function() { //// Page has loaded and theme assets are ready
(function() {
    var f = function() {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            // Minimum view count
            var minViews = 2;
            // Maximum view count
            var maxViews = 20;
            // Text to show after the view count number
            var text = 'people are viewing this product right now.';


            // Create the new element to display on the page
            $(".view-count").get().forEach(function(entry, index, array) {
                var $viewCountElement = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxViews - minViews) + minViews) + ' ' + text;
                $(entry).html($viewCountElement);
            });

        });
    };
    window.setInterval(f, 10000); //10 sec interval
    f();
})();
});
```

Comment: It looks like your function is just adding an event listener to the `DOMContentLoaded` event, which happens only once. You just keep adding more event listeners, but the event never happens again.

Answer (score 1):

You may not need nested event listener. You can just call the `setInterval` in the call back function of `DOMContentLoaded`.

```
function elementDisplay() {
  // Minimum view count
  var minViews = 2;
  // Maximum view count
  var maxViews = 20;
  // Text to show after the view count number
  var text = 'people are viewing this product right now.';


  // Create the new element to display on the page
  $(".view-count").get().forEach(function(entry, index, array) {
    var $viewCountElement = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxViews - minViews) + minViews) + ' ' + text;
    $(entry).html($viewCountElement);
  });

}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  window.setInterval(elementDisplay, 10000); //10 sec interval
});
```

Comment: Ah I see. But this piece of code would mean that it wont run intially and then every 10 seconds, right? Because the function gets called after a 10 sec interval.

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` is a browser based API, zo it should be cleaned up from the browser properly.

This is majorly for your proper implementation of `setInterval`. You can add your listeners, too.

FYI: `jQuery.ready`/`DOMContentLoaded` occurs when all of the HTML is ready to interact with, but often before its been rendered to the screen.

```js
var interval;
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("I am initialized")
  var f = function() {
    console.log("I am called")
    // Minimum view count
    var minViews = 2;
    // Maximum view count
    var maxViews = 20;
    // Text to show after the view count number
    var text = 'people are viewing this product right now.';
    // Create the new element to display on the page
    $(".view-count").get().forEach(function(entry, index, array) {
      var $viewCountElement = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxViews - minViews) + minViews) + ' ' + text;
      $(entry).html($viewCountElement);
    });
  };
  interval = setInterval(f, 10000);

});

$(window).on("beforeunload", function() {
  // clear the interval when window closes
  return clearInterval(interval);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note: Check the console for output